# Posting answers through an iPhone

Tags: discussion, questions, comments, asking-questions, mobile-web

Which directives or symbols are used to format codes when posting answers and comments from an iPhone and Android?

Comment: Why would it be any different on the mobile site? Backticks for inline code, block indents (4 spaces) for code blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've always used the same [Markdown formatting notation](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Surround text spans with backticks (`) for inline code spans, or indent each line of a block with four spaces for code blocks:

[image: Mobile Markdown]

Comment: Damn the Retina display sure blows things up. Maybe I should retake this in the iOS Simulator instead.

Comment: ... never mind, the simulator doesn't even pick up the mobile theme.

Comment: @Rick Sladkey: Much better. Thanks!

Comment: Just confirming: the post/edit/comment backend code is exactly the same for mobile.  Exactly the same markdown conventions apply.